# Does the return statement supersedes the other return statement in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, return

If i use a code like shown below,why the upper return statement takes precedence and the other return statemend after braces does not get executed.

```
function some4(array, f) {
  for (let i of array) {
    if (f(i)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: [The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

Comment: As soon as a return is met, the function exits. If the first return is met, the function will exit, so the second will never be reached and will never run.

Comment: try to think, what you want your function to achieve / return. You want it to find a value `i` which makes function `f` valid. Then you return at that point with that result (`true`). Else if that does not happen you finally  return with `false`. Simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because once the return is executed it will terminate that function.